# Hunter Ceiling Fan No Longer Works

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I hope you can give me a few suggestions with this one. We have a hunter ceiling fan that is wall switch connected for master power.  This spring it started having a few issues.  This fan is remote controlled with no external pull strings or controls other than the remote. The problem is that the fan is intermittent. When the wall switch is placed on the light comes on, which means it has power.  That can be turned off with the remote.  Using the remote 80% of the time you can get the fan to move in low and medium settings but never in the high setting.  The reverse switch will also work on the remote, changing the fan direction.  Sometimes the fan will not work at all.  When this happens you can sometimes get it to work by selecting low or medium fan speed and reversing the direction. Any time the remote switches are used you can hear the switches in the fan actuating including when you use the high power setting, but the fan will not spin. For that reason I do not think this is a power supply or remote issue.  I think this may be a solid state issue with the fan motor.  Rather replacing the whole thing, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are its the starter capacitor. This is the device used to give the motor an initial boost of power to overcome the initial load required to get the fan to start. 
[image]

If you can open the fan, you may see this component swelled up and melted, if so, you will need to replace with a suitable candidate (read the text of the starting capacitor)

Comment: You may also have to replace the fan receiver.  I have changed one, the other or sometime both on a lot of fans.

Comment: Only thing is he could hear the fan clicking, meaning the receiver is picking up signal and relay switches are kicking in.